# AttributeError: 'Meta' object has no attribute 'app_config'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run an already existing project on my local machine from a git repo. Trying to run the command "python manage.py runserver" produces an `AttributeError`.

The error is on line 81:

```
def check(self, app_configs):

    if app_configs is None:
        app_configs = apps.get_app_configs()
    app_configs = set(app_configs)  # Speed up lookups below

    errors = []
    modeladmins = (o for o in self._registry.values() if o.__class__ is not ModelAdmin)
    for modeladmin in modeladmins:
        if modeladmin.model._meta.app_config in app_configs: #ErrorHere
            errors.extend(modeladmin.check())
    return errors
```

**ERROR ON COMMAND PROMPT**

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x0000000005D14128>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\osola\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\osola\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\osola\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\osola\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\osola\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\osola\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 25, in check_admin_app
    errors.extend(site.check(app_configs))
  File "C:\Users\osola\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 80, in check
    if modeladmin.model._meta.app_config in app_configs:
AttributeError: 'Meta' object has no attribute 'app_config'
```

Comment: Please post errors as text instead of screenshots. If you google for the error `'Meta' object has no attribute 'app_config'`, it looks as if you might be hitting [this issue](https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance/issues/148) in django-constance. It's tricky to help further without knowing the code and the versions of the installed packages.

Comment: @Alasdair please see below my list of packages: Django==1.11.4
django-allauth==0.33.0
django-appconf==1.0.2
django-celery-email==1.1.4
django-compressor==2.2
django-constance==1.2
django-countries==5.0
django-extensions==1.9.6
django-heartbeat==2.0.2
django-honeypot==0.6.0
django-modelcluster==3.1
django-picklefield==1.0.0
django-taggit==0.22.1
django-tastypie==0.14.0
django-treebeard==4.1.2
django-webtest==1.9.2
djangorestframework==3.6.4

Comment: I would try to upgrading django-constance. The latest version is 2.0.0, but you may find that 1.3.4 works better with other packages.

Comment: @Alasdair upgrading the django-costance appears to have worked. Thanks for assisting